# How to add extra lines in eclipse debug mode?

Tags: eclipse

I need to add extra lines in debug mode. For example here is the sample program.

```
public static void main(){
System.out.println("First line");
System.out.println("Third line");
}
```

I will run this program in debug mode keeping break point at first sysout. In debug mode I will add another line between the 2 sysouts like below :

```
public static void main(){
System.out.println("First line");
System.out.println("Second line");
System.out.println("Third line");
}
```

Now without terminating the debug mode I want normal execution of the program that means I want second sysout also needs to be printed. Can any one please suggest me.

Comment: You really should at least try it and see if it works (don't forget to build the changes).

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse Java debugger has "Hot code replacement" feature. Whenever you change the code during debug session then given part of code will be gets compiled and loaded into debug session automatically.

Note `Project > Build automatically` option should be enabled.